# Split words with linked list in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, linked-list

I have problem with linked list. I wrote a function want to split a sentence into words. Like I have a sentence "I love you", and it splits into 3 words "I", "love", "you". I have the head pointer to the first letter of the sentence. And the function will return an array with every words' head pointers.

It works fine only has one problem. If one word just have one letter. It will combine with the second word. Like "I love you", it will give the words as "I love" and "love", "you".

I have thought for a long time and other functions work well. I think the problem is in the for loop, can anyone helps?

```
Node* SplitToWords(Node* cursor){
int i=CountWords(cursor);

Node* array=new Node[i];
Node* t;
t=cursor;

for (int j=0; j<i-1; j++) {
    array[j]=*t;
    t=t->link;
    while (t->data!=' ') {
        cursor=t;
        t=t->link;
    }
    t=t->link;
    cursor->link=NULL;
}
array[i-1]=*t;

return array;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through it in a debugger?

Comment: Consider using Boost Tokenizer (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/tokenizer/), which solves this problem.

Comment: Yes, I have tried. I don't know why if is one letter word the "cursor->link=NULL;" does not work...

Comment: follow the code in the debugger, do not say 'i dont know why cursor->link=NULL does not work'. YOu should ask, 'my code does not do what I expect, so what is it actually doing'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You process first letter of a word wrong. This `array[j]=*t;` copy node to array. And in the end `cursor->link=NULL;` doesn't make any changes in this copy if you word one letter long.
To fix you can remember first node and insert it into array in the end of the `for` loop

```
for (int j=0; j<i-1; j++) {
    Node *first_letter = t;
    t=t->link;
    while (t->data!=' ') {
        cursor=t;
        t=t->link;
    }
    t=t->link;
    cursor->link=NULL;
    array[j]=*first_letter;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am still studying pointer and I forgot this problem. Thank you for help!!!!